# Can I use the eyedropper when "Recoloring Artwork" on illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I use Illustrator CC. And I use the recolor artwork option from the "Edit > Edit colors" menu.

Is there a way to choose the color I switch to with the eyedropper tool?

Answer (score 2):

- Copy the Hexadecimal Color Number from the Color Picker
- Select the Artwork > **Menu Edit** > **Edit colors** > **Recolor Artwork**
- After selecting the coloring option to 1 color, double click the New Color thumbnail > Paste the Hexadecimal Number at the color picker hexadecimal field

[image: hexacolors]

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question now to be more precise.

Comment: I'm using the Recolor Artwork for years and I did not notice I  could do this method. Great!